# Parameter in order by clause doesn't order -mysql, C#

Tags: mysql

In my mvc application i am using following query to select some data.I am not using stored procedure

```
 select recordID,ChannelID,UserID ,StartTime ,Duration,SeqNum from result  WHERE SeqNum = ?pSeqNum
             ORDER BY StartTime  DESC limit ?pStartIndex, ?pRecordsPerPage;
```

I will pass  values to LIMT. and  Its works fine.

Now i gave an option to user to select order by condition (user select one from recordID,ChannelID,UserID ,StartTime ,Duration) .
So o tried following  code.

```
 select recordID,ChannelID,UserID ,StartTime ,Duration,SeqNum from result  WHERE SeqNum = ?pSeqNum
             ORDER BY ?pOrderBy  DESC limit ?pStartIndex, ?pRecordsPerPage;
```

I passed values for pOrderBy as i passes for pStartIndex, and pRecordsPerPage.
But its not working order By. Its only selecting the data without order by

Comment: Check whether the value for pOrderBy is passed correctly, there may be a mismatch in naming conventions

Comment: I am passing pOrderBy as a string

Comment: Just echo the mysql query to see what the exact query that is passing.. I think u should hv made a mistake as posted by Phil Brown..

Comment: @kvijayhari The queries are already shown above

Comment: @phil brown : I was saying him that he would have made the mistake as stated by you in your post.. :) May be i should have used the word stated instead of posted

Comment: @kvijayhari Sorry, I should have explained further. You can't dump a prepared statement with its parameters substituted in. The best you can do is what is above, show the statement with placeholders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `ORDER BY` uses a database identifier (ie, a column, alias or expression). You are passing the value as a parameter.

In other words, the resulting query would be equivalent to

```
... ORDER BY 'StartTime' ...
```

If you validate the user input against a known set of values (ie, the available columns), you can simply interpolate the value into the query string, eg (very rough)

```
$orderBy = $_GET['order_by'];
if (!in_array($orderBy, $orderableColumns)) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid "order by" specified');
}
$query = sprintf('... ORDER BY `%s` ...', $orderBy);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe the `order by` clause can be parameterized.  Definitely not in Oracle, not 100% sure about MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can `SELECT` the sorting column using a `CASE WHEN` condition based on a parameter, give it a name then sort by that column.

```
SELECT col1, col2, 
(CASE ?param 
  WHEN 'col3' THEN col3 
  WHEN 'col4' THEN col4
END) As MyOrder  

FROM myTable
ORDER BY MyOrder
```

We'll be adding one additional column to the results and I think it won't benefit from indexed columns, slowing the query down, but it works.